# How to reduce the execution time of a custom perceptron class?

Tags: python, performance, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I have written a custom Perceptron class and tried to classify the breast cancer dataset provided by scikit-learn with it. Afterward, I attempted the same task with the Perceptron that scikit-learn provides and compared the time my implementation and scikit-learn implementation took. I have found my code to take much longer than scikit-learn. My code takes 7-9 seconds for each iteration, but the scikit-learn Perceptron is instantaneous.

[image: Time taken for My Perceptron (left) vs Sklearn Perceptron (right)]

The code for my Perceptron is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
import time

class CustomPerceptron():
    '''
    Parameters:
    n_iterations: int
    Number of epochs the perceptron will run on the dataset
    
    learning_rate: float
    Learning rate to adjust the weights. Value between 0 and 1
    
    random_state: int
    Used in the random number generator to generate different weights every time
    '''
    def __init__(self, n_iterations=100, learning_rate=0.01, random_state=1):
        self.n_iterations = n_iterations
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.random_state = random_state
 
    
    '''
    Parameters:
    X: Sample dataset
    y: Target values
    '''
    def fit(self, X, y):
        rgen = np.random.RandomState(self.random_state)
        self.weights_ = rgen.normal(loc=0.0, scale=0.01, size=1 + X.shape[1])
        self.errors_ = []
        for _ in range(self.n_iterations):
            errors = 0
            for xi, expected_value in zip(X, y):
                predicted_value = self.predict(xi)
                self.weights_[1:] = self.weights_[1:] + self.learning_rate * (expected_value - predicted_value) * xi
                self.weights_[0] = self.weights_[0] + self.learning_rate * (expected_value - predicted_value) * 1
                update = self.learning_rate * (expected_value - predicted_value)
                errors += int(update != 0.0)
            self.errors_.append(errors)
    
    
    '''
    Parameters:
    X: Sample dataset
    
    Returns:
    Weighted sum of each data point and its corresponding weight with the bias added
    '''
    def net_input(self, X):
            weighted_sum = np.dot(X, self.weights_[1:]) + self.weights_[0]
            return weighted_sum
     
    
    '''
    Parameters:
    X: Sample dataset
    
    Returns:
    nd-array where each element is 1 or 0 depending on the weighted sum
    '''
    def activation_function(self, X):
            weighted_sum = self.net_input(X)
            return np.where(weighted_sum >= 0.0, 1, 0)
     
    
    '''
    Parameters:
    X: Sample dataset
    
    Returns:
    Predicted values on the basis of the output of activation function
    '''
    def predict(self, X):
        return self.activation_function(X)
     
    
    '''
    Parameters:
    X: Sample dataset
    y: Target values
    
    Returns:
    Accuracy of the model on the sample dataset
    '''
    def accuracy(self, X, y):
        misclassified_data_count = 0
        for xi, target in zip(X, y):
            output = self.predict(xi)
            if(target != output):
                misclassified_data_count += 1
        total_data_count = len(X)
        self.score_ = (total_data_count - misclassified_data_count) / total_data_count
        return self.score_
    
    
    '''
    Parameters:
    X: Sample dataset
    y: Target values
    
    Returns:
    A tuple of size 3 where
    index 0: Precision
    index 1: Recall
    index 2: F1 score
    '''
    def metrics(self, X, y):
        TP, TN, FP, FN = 0, 0, 0, 0
        for xi, target in zip(X, y):
            output = self.predict(xi)
            if(target == 1 and output == 1):
                TP += 1
            elif(target == 0 and output == 0):
                TN += 1
            elif(target == 0 and output == 1):
                FP += 1
            elif(target == 1 and output == 0):
                FN += 1
        
        precision = TP / (TP + FP)
        recall = TP / (TP + FN)
        f1_score = (2 * precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
        
        return (precision, recall, f1_score)
```

Each Perceptron runs for 1000 epochs, and I have performed the classification 100 times in a for loop. The code is given:

```
bc = datasets.load_breast_cancer()
X = bc.data
y = bc.target

accuracy_list = []
our_times = []
precisions = []
recalls = []
f1s = []
sklearn_accuracy_list = []
sklearn_times = []
sklearn_precisions = []
sklearn_recalls = []
sklearn_f1s = []

ppn = CustomPerceptron(n_iterations=1000) # our Perceptron
clf = Perceptron(tol=1e-3, eta0=0.01, random_state=0) # sklearn Perceptron

for i in range(100):
    # train-test (80-20) split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=i, stratify=y)
    
    start_time = time.time() # start tracking time for our Perceptron
    ppn.fit(X_train, y_train) # fit training data to our Perceptron
    accuracy_list.append(ppn.accuracy(X_test, y_test)) # calculate accuracy of our Perceptron on test data and add to list
    end_time = time.time() # end tracking time for our Perceptron
    our_times.append(end_time - start_time) # calculate time taken by our Perceptron for 1 iteration and add to list
    
    start_time = time.time() # start tracking time for sklearn Perceptron
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train) # fit training data to sklearn Perceptron
    sklearn_accuracy_list.append(clf.score(X_test, y_test)) # calculate accuracy of sklearn Perceptron on test data and add to list
    end_time = time.time() # end tracking time for sklearn Perceptron
    sklearn_times.append(end_time - start_time) # calculate time taken by sklearn Perceptron for 1 iteration and add to list
```

I want to optimize the performance of my Perceptron and reduce the gap between my implementation and the scikit-learn implementation. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mind to add imports? As `numpy`, `datasets` and so on?

Comment: Why do you expect a pure-Python implementation certainly executed in the CPython interpreter to be as fast as a code certainly using native code (Cython or C extensions) ?

Comment: @rpanai I have added the imports.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I just want to know if there is any way I can reduce the gap between my implementation and the sklearn one.

Comment: Show us measured evidence of where the hotspots are. Compare with a sklearn run. https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile